# MongoDB java and updating values

Tags: java, mongodb, replace

So I'm trying to edit a value on the MongoDB, but I don't really know how to do it.
I've made 2 methods, (I need both even if I can do in one, I'm using both to get the user elo in other classes).

Getting the user's elo works

```
    // Get user elo
    public int getUserElo(UUID uuid) {
        return this.collection.find(new BasicDBObject("uuid", uuid.toString())).first().getInt("elo");
    }
```

But not adding user's elo

```
    // Add user elo
    public void addUserElo(UUID uuid, int elo) {
        this.collection.find(new BasicDBObject("uuid", uuid)).first().append("elo", getUserElo(uuid) - elo);
    }
```

So when I'm trying to add 'elo' to a user with this method, the whole document is replaced with the only value 'elo'

My database is made on this constructor:

```
    public PlayerInfo(String username, UUID uuid, String joindate, int elo) {
        this.username = username;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.joindate = joindate;
        this.elo = elo;
    }
```

EDIT:
The method, add elo doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
I've found how to do it
Here is how for people in troubles.

```
    // Add user elo
    public void addUserElo(UUID uuid, int elo) {
        this.collection.updateOne(new BasicDBObject("uuid", uuid.toString()), set("elo", getUserElo(uuid) + elo));
    }
```